# Scan a small compiled .net executable for vulnerabilities

Tags: c#, .net, security

I have a small compiled c#.net executable used for running third-party external software installers and pulling some system information through WMI.

Is there a resource I can use either in Visual Studio or some other tool to run a vulnerability scan on the executable to ensure the code isn't easily exploitable?

Comment: [Code analysis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z0aeatx.aspx).

Comment: The first run looks good but I'll have to do more digging to figure out proper fixes for the warnings I'm receiving.  Thank you!